# Can this Delay Differential Equation (DDE) be solved in closed form?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, delay-differential-equations

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\psi}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{(x+\mu)^2-\lambda^2}{\mu}\psi(x+\mu)$$
where $\mu\geq0$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ are constants and $\psi(x)\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

Comment: I tried to solve it through the Fourier Transform but I got stuck: the Fourier Transform should solve the following differential equation $$G''(w)+\left(\lambda^2-iw\mu \,e^{iw\mu}\right)G(w)=0$$ but I don't know how to solve it. Maybe ask for the differential equation in MSE.

Comment: Yes, it can. $\psi(x)=0$ is a solution.