# It is possible to solve this kind of ODE: $G''(w)+\left(\lambda^2-iw\mu \,e^{iw\mu}\right)G(w)=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, delay-differential-equations

**It is possible to solve this kind of ODE: $G''(w)+\left(\lambda^2-iw\mu \,e^{iw\mu}\right)G(w)=0$?**

where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are real-valued constants.

**Motivation**

I am looking for examples of [Delayed Differential Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) (DDE) with closed-form solutions, and looking for them I found this [question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1725212/909869) where someone ask for solving an example. By applying the Fourier Transform I found the equation of this question (hopefully I don't made any mistake), but I never tried to solve before an ODE with complex non-constant coefficients:

**Are there method for solving these kind of equations with closed-form solutions?**,

Wolfram-Alpha don't give any answer neither clues for what I should be looking for.

So far the only DDEs with close-form solution I have found is Wikipedia example:
$$x'(t) = -x(t-1) \quad\Rightarrow x(t)=e^{t\ W_k(-1)}$$
with $W_k(t)$ the [Lambert W-Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html), and I don't have any clue so far about how the parameter $k$ is determined from the initial values.

Comment: These kind of equations admit formal series solutions in inverse powers of $\lambda$. Look up the WKB method.